# Is there a method to find a blender project which contains a particular named mesh

Tags: objects

I seem to have forgotten the name of a blender file I worked on a few weeks ago and I have too many blender files to wade through.
I know that it contained a mesh with a particular name.
Is there any method how to find a project which contains a particular mesh name?

Comment: That's not really a Blender question, more about the PC operating system that you're using. If it's Windows I'd uses something like the free version of [Agent Ransack](https://download.mythicsoft.com/flp/3389/agentransack_3389.exe) with 'Look in:' set to the folder where you keep your Blend files, the 'File Name:' as '*.blend' and the 'Containing text:' set to your mesh name.

Comment: Sorry John. I wasn't sure if such 'text' names would be 'modified' (eg compressed or whatever) within the Blender project file and that there was a function within Blender to do such a search. I have seen files in the past which when edited are just a maze of undecipherable (hexadecimal) characters.

Comment: No the object names aren't modified if you save your blend files uncompressed (the default). Any data file seems to be undecipherable code if you look at it with a text editor. However, if you searched within that code for the object name in a Blend file you would see it in plain text.

Comment: Hi :). This should be possible by linking all of the blends into one file, and then searching for that specific name. The resulting search should give the name of the linked file.